# How to capture browser close event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

I want to capture the browser close event in my application and show a confirm box to user.
I am using JSF 2.0 and richfaces 4.0.

Answer (score 17):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () 
{
  var shallIAlertUser = Do_Whatever(); //get boolen value
  if (shallIAlertUser) {
    //this will alert user
    return 'Are you sure?';
  }
  else {
    //this wont
    window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {

    event = event || window.event;

    var confirmClose = 'Are you sure?';

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (event) {
       event.returnValue = confirmClose;
    }

    // For Safari
    return confirmClose;

}
```

Keep in mind this will be fire for other events besides closing the window, such as reloading and form submission.

Comment: Is the same for Alt-F4, and close the navigator (tab or X ) and too F5 key, postback and reload ?

Answer (score 5):

`onbeforeunload`

```
< body onbeforeunload="alert('Closing');">
```

**Example :**

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>`onbeforeunload` Event Demo</title>
</head>
<body onbeforeunload="return 'Are you sure you want to exit ?';">
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `beforeunload` event is meant to return a `string`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the info. OP just want a function call

Answer (score 1):

Attach a handler to the `unload` event.

Comment: I tried with onbeforeunload event. But the issue is when I refresh the page or do any form submission, it also call the onbeforeunload event.

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between those; the browser can only tell you that the current document is about to be replaced. That doesn't give you an idea *why*