# how stop session (tracking) in google analytic

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I use code from google analytic home page with remote ga.js. All works cool beside one thing: Avg. Time on Page. I close page in browser but my session leaves active. 
I want to stop session from JS handy. I try search but nothing.
How can i do it ?

**UPDATE**

You miss me. I **know** that moment when say to GA that session is closed. My app plays in UIWebView on iOs. So I want to send termination when app is exited. 
It's so simple. Isn't ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not know the difference between a page close and a page refresh and a page navigation away. Plus there is no reliable way with JavaScript to send the information to the server when the unload event is called.

Comment: i know it. I want send a message to GA server to terminate current  session. Fe, _gaq.push(['_stop']).

Comment: JavaScript can not do it, it has no clue if the browser is closing.

Comment: That's not entirely true @epascarello, it has a clue its just not consistent in all browsers and situations. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript

Comment: @shanabus onbeforeunload fires for any event that causes the page to leave, refresh, exit. You can not tell the difference. You can send a ping to the server from here, but it is a race condition with the page closing and the call going out. I know this, I code this in my application with my custom logging framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to delete the `_utmb` cookie:

[Cookies Set By Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html#cookiesSet)

```
function del_cookie(name) {
   document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT;';
} 

del_cookie("_utmb");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the true time on site/page
Have a look to the [strategy proposed by Savio](http://www.savio.no/blogg/a/96/how-to-measure-true-time-with-google-analytics)