# How to end sessions automatically if user closes the browser

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I need to end the session automatically when the user is inactive for some particular time say for 10 minutes. We have a method in

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("User", au);
session.setAttribute("name", firstname);
response.sendRedirect("doLogin.jsp");
session.setMaxInterval();
```

but this will end the session even if the user is active for 10 minutes. How can I end the session when the user closes the browser?

Comment: User is active but session ends anyway? Looks like a bug. What Server do you use?

Comment: The session can't end when the browser has been closed. There must be a triggerd Request that has been send when the browser close.

Comment: @PeterRader please tell me how to do so

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Avoid manual code for that.

simply in `web.xml`   `//this will applied for whole application`

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Detect browser close event and  call [invalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#invalidate%28%29) method

```
if(session!=null) { 
session.invalidate();   
}
```

Comment: i know this but my question is how to close the session when browser is closed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript

Comment: thanks for the answer. Well i have last requirement the way i did now accepts multiple login at the same time using a same username and password.for example username x can login at the same time from mozilla,chrome and etc. But i do not want this way suppose if username x login from mozillla and later he logins from chrome the in mozilla it will get loged out automatically.please tell me how to do this

Comment: you can go through :http://www.xyzws.com/Servletfaq/when-do-i-use-httpsessionbindinglistener/6

Comment: You got it?? let me know if you need any furthur clarrifications.

Comment: thanks for replying i went through the sites you have suggested but i could not get how to implement it

Comment: yeah.thats quite tricky..when you are rediricting your user to dashboard or what ever after login..just before that bind  the user name or user object to that session then you will get a call in onvalue bound and maintain a map with session and user ..from next time onwords check that map.dont forget to remove him when logout.and you can google it for full fledged example.good luck

Comment: @Baadshah Making references to roseindia here can cause you some trouble.

Comment: Oops.. let me delete it. thanks for the help.I don't know that @skuntsel

Comment: @Baadshah see after login it is going to dologin.jsp where it matches with the username and password and if it is true then i am setting attribute here.how will i check if multiple persons are trying to login from one username

Answer (score 6):

You can set the session time out as below in the [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html):

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60); //in seconds
```

This will give you the advantage that you can read the session timeout from any external properties file/ database and change the session timeout without changing the code.

You can use the [`unload`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) event and send the logout request to the server. Or keep sending periodic requests to the server informing the user is still active.

Comment: how to close the session when browser is closed

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the session timeout, that is, the time after which current `Session` object will be invalidated.

This can be done either by setting timeout in your web.xml like:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

or programmatically call on the `Session` object

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(valueInSeconds);
```

Keep an eye that session timeout period set up in web.xml is in minutes, and programmatically - in seconds.

Comment: thanks for answering but i know this i wanted to end the session when user closes the browser

Comment: You should capture browser close event in javascript and logout the user. Find a Q/A [how to capture brower close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Exactly, and call logout servlet from the JavaScript event.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to intimate the server about the user closes the browser. That's why the sessions are having configurable timespan. If you wanna do it then try by creating a onclose javascript event and from there do an ajax call to intimate the session close to the server. In the server you can get the session id from this call as parameter and kill it.

I didn't tried it. Don't think it is right to do.

Answer (score 0):

Question: How to end sessions automatically if **user closes the browser**?

Answer: **Set max inactive interval** time value less than 0.

Example:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);
session.setAttribute("User", au);
response.sendRedirect("doLogin.jsp");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do that from web config file. A sample is here

```
 <sessionState 
        mode="InProc" 
        stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
        stateNetworkTimeout="10" 
        sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
        sqlCommandTimeout="30" 
        customProvider="" 
        cookieless="UseCookies" 
        cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" 
        timeout="10" 
        allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" 
        regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
        partitionResolverType="" 
        useHostingIdentity="true">
        <providers>
         <clear />
        </providers>
   </sessionState>
```

The timeout property will specify the timeout period.