# invalidate session ,when thebrowser was closed without logout

Tags: jsp, session-state

I am trying to invalidate the session when the user closes the browser without logging out. I tried using generated event `unLoad`, but this event also fired when the user refreshes the page or presses the back button. So i want to invalidate the session when the browser closes.

If the user logs out normally I am invalidating the session using the code `session.invalidate();`, but if the user closes the browser the session is not invalidated until container specific time out. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16272150/2630817

Comment: You must ask if some one closing tab, and invalidate it

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery

Comment: thanks for the reply,i verified your links,but i didn't get any soluetion

Answer (score 1):

You can add window unload hook,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {    
if (event) {
       //code to invalidate session
    }    
}
```

Comment: this will also be triggered when the page is refreshed.

Comment: @onepotato yes , your right this will also be triggered