# how to find first request in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I want to find the first request which is coming to jsp. Once a window is closed, again I want to find the first request coming to jsp, but I do not want to restart my server. I am trying this:

```
String name=session.getAttribute("val"); 
if(name!=null)
{
//something
}
else
{
//something
}
```

It is working only for the first request. After that, I have to restart the server again and again.

Moreover, I want to find the time spent on particular jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the data in Server **Session**. It has **invalidation period** (configurable, let's say 10 min for example), so it is cleared only after this period. Closing the window doesn't affect this logic at all.

Handling of window behavior should be done on client side with **Javascript**. Take a look at `window.onload` and `window.onbeforeunload` events.

Time spent on the page can also be captured on client side. In general the logic could be:

1. When page loaded (`onload` event) you start the timer.
2. When page is unloaded (`onbeforeunload` event) you save timer value to some local storage of sending it to server with `ajax` call.

Comment: then how to find time spent on specific jsp

Comment: I has added some comments on this

Comment: i have tried this window.onbeforeunload = function () 
{ 
return "Are you sure"; 
}; but it is not working in chrome in 34.0....

Comment: It is a separate issue) And, as I see, already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626059/window-onbeforeunload-in-chrome-what-is-the-most-recent-fix

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for.

- [How to end sessions automatically if user closes the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272137/how-to-end-sessions-automatically-if-user-closes-the-browser?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Killing session when closing the browser](http://www.coderanch.com/t/533186/JSP/java/Killing-session-closing-browser)

Try with below options:

- web.xml

  ```
  <session-config>
      <session-timeout> 5 </session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  ```
- `HttpSession.invalidate()`
- set the `cache-control` meta tag in the header to `no cache` to prevent session reuse.