# How to pop up message on closing web browser

Tags: javascript

I need to find browser close button click event in my web application. I need to show some alert message on that event. I tried to do it using  window.onbeforeunload event, but it gets called on every page navigation or page refresh 
 I need to execute that function only on close button click event

Comment: Have you tried onbeforeunload? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript

Comment: Check this post. Checks to see if user has clicks link or submitted form http://stackoverflow.com/a/1632004/2637902

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PSLuP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  });
});
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window)