# window.onunload event not firing

Tags: javascript

I have a silverlight application in which I need to fire signout event if user navigates away.
I have tried a sample function as

```
window.onunload = function test() { alert("test"); }
```

The problem is when I navigate away from the webpage the event fires, but I need this event to fire when user closed browser or tab.

Comment: You can not do this, what happens when the browser crashes, they just close the window, etc. You will not get the event on the server. Use session timeouts!

Comment: You could find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was not necessary that the page prompts user if he is sure he wants to exit. So I called my signout method inside the 'window.onbeforeunload' event(also flashed a message box to so that webservice gets enough time to successfully signout). 
Also used

```
document.onbeforeunload = undefined;
```

inside my 'window.onbeforeunload' event to avoid the confirmation window.