# How to get the browser close event in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I write a some function like abc() and this function call when browser is closed.

Condition is that the method is execute when browser is called not any other event like page reload,navigate etc.

Give me the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event

Comment: you can't. instead you can use jQuery [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) which is `onBeforeUnload`

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  If it was possible all sorts of annying things would happen. 
the closest you can get is onBeforeUnload.

Comment: onBeforeUnload() event call when page is refresh or reload. and also work on when browser is close.

Comment: yeah, but you do anything useful in the onbeforeunload event

Comment: i am use this event it work but this event execute when page is reload or refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script> 
$( window ).unload(function() 
{
   abc(); //your function name 
});
</script>
```

Comment: This event execute when page is reload or refresh

Comment: I want which event execute when browser is close not page is reload or refresh.

Comment: you can use onclick to disable the onbeforeunload if they navigate. I don't have a solution for refresh (or back).