# How to automatically logoff user whenever the user closes the tab

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am working on dotnetnuke website. I want to logoff the user when he closes the browser or tab. Please help me to resolve this. How can I detect browser close event and how can logout the user.

Comment: Probably this can help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event

Comment: I don't  want to display any message I just want to clear the session to logout the user. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect the browser close or tab close using javascript.

Only you can know the page unload, the following events are [OnBeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) &
[OnUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)
Neither of these events can tell you the way that you closed the page.