# Detect via js a browser window/tab close event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to detect if a user is leaving my websites. Like a window/tab close event of the webbrowser or by following a link to a other domain.

In some searches I found some solutions, but they alert ever when a link is clicked, also on my pages. As example I tried out this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {

event = event || window.event;

var confirmClose = 'Are you sure?';

// For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
if (event) {
   event.returnValue = confirmClose;
}

// For Safari
return confirmClose;

}
```

So what do I have to modify so that the alert is deactivated when I'm browsing through my domain?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event (TL;DR: attach an event to internal links that unbinds the onbeforeunload alert before it fires)

Comment: Yeah your right. That works fine. Thanks

Comment: you can't do it that way, the function will prevent what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can't know where you are going when the onbeforeunload fires. And the purpose is basically to prevent exactly what you are trying to achieve.