# PHP attachement upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, upload

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="title">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description"></textarea>
  <input type="file" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to upload the files when user selects them (onChange event) and get an ID. With that ID I can create inputs like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="ID" name="images[]">
```

I can upload those file with Ajax, but let's suppose that for some reason user's browser closes or his computer shutdowns before user actually click submit button. How can I delete those files from server and database ?

Comment: beforeunload event may do it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event)

Comment: beforeunload won't work when problems like forced shutdown  occur

Comment: Create a cron job that periodically checks for files uploaded but not associated in your database.

Comment: @Nick but I need to get file id from database.  I thought about  a "is_tmp" on "uploads" table

Comment: Or better yet, upload the files to a temp folder and when the forms gets submited, move the file to their designated location. Then you can create a cron job that every night deletes the images from the temp folder.

Comment: If you need file id, then why not create a table in db, named temp_files insert when file upload with default status as 0 and image_id, turn status 1 when images[] array posted 

Run cron on server once a day and remove all images from folder those have status as 0