# How can I get a timestamp when PHP session ends?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

Is it possible to get a timestamp, and have that timestamp saved as a cookie or even into mysql database when a PHP session is timed out?
I've been fiddling with the expiry times and want to have reassurance of how long the sessions are lasting for.

And that way I can see what time people log in and what time they are either kicked out or logged out.

Comment: if you really want to sneak upon the activity time, you can insert time in db when a user is logged in and update it when he logs out ? Why don't you go with this approach ?

Comment: I'm going to do that as well but it's rare that someone actually logs out, they typically just close the browser.

Comment: You could fire a AJAX post somewhere to record it in the database after an 'onbeforeunload' event is executed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event