# How can I update the offline, online status of my displayed users in every 5 seconds?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have made a messaging feature of my application, In my code, I have given is the showing of the users which are receivers of the messages, I want to know beside their name their status if they are online or not which is noted by a red dot image for offline and green dot image for the online, it worked when I run it and used two kinds of browser, chrome and mozilla for two different accounts. What my problem is when I logged out an account, it doesn't go to red dot as offline in the other account. I want to update their status every 5 seconds, I've already made a script but I can't see the changing of online/offline status every 5 seconds.

My displaying of receiver users and their messages code:

```
<?php 
require('connection.php');
$user_name=$_SESSION['username'];
$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    header("LOCATION: index.php");
}else{
    $advance_time=time()+15;
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM status WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE status SET status='$advance_time' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    }else{
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO status(user_id,status) VALUES ('$user_id','$advance_time')");
    }
}
?>
<div id="left-col-container">
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById('new-message').style.display='block'" class="white-back">
<p align="center">New Message </p>
</div>

<?php 

$q='SELECT DISTINCT `receiver_name`,`sender_name`,`date_time`
FROM `messages` WHERE 
`sender_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'" OR
`receiver_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC';
$e='SELECT * from messages';
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);


if($r){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0){
        $counter=0;
        $added_user=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
            $sender_name=$row['sender_name'];
            $receiver_name=$row['receiver_name'];
            $timestamp=$row['date_time'];
            if($_SESSION['username']==$sender_name){
                //add the receiver_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($receiver_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add receiver_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the receiver_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
                    <?php 
                    echo '<a href="?user='.$receiver_name.'">'.$receiver_name.'</a>';
                   $fetch_content=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while($row_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)){
                        $time=$row_fetch[5];
                        if($time<= time()){
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }else{
                            $status= "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                     echo $status;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as receiver_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$receiver_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }elseif($_SESSION['username']==$receiver_name){
                //add the sender_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($sender_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add sender_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the sender_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
                    <?php echo '<a href="?user='.$sender_name.'">'.$sender_name.'</a>';
                      $fetch_content=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while($row_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)){
                        $time=$row_fetch[5];
                        if($time<= time()){
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }else{
                            $status= "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                     echo $status;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as sender_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$sender_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            }
        }
        else{
        //no message sent
        echo 'no user';
        }
    }else{
    //query problem
    echo $q;
}
?>



<!-- end of left-col-container -->
</div>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" id="from_user_id">
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){updating_status()},5000);
function updating_status(){
    let this_user = $('#from_user_id').val(); 
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "updating.php",
        data: {from_user:this_user},
    success: function(response){
        $('#content').html(response);
    }
    });
}
</script>
```

and my updating.php code:

```
<?php
 require('connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['from_user'])){
 $advance_time=time()+15;
 $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
 $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM status WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE status SET status='$advance_time' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    }else{
        mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO status(user_id,status) VALUES ('$user_id','$advance_time')");
?>
<div id="left-col-container">
<div style="cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById('new-message').style.display='block'" class="white-back">
<p align="center">New Message </p>
</div>

<?php 

$q='SELECT DISTINCT `receiver_name`,`sender_name`,`date_time`
FROM `messages` WHERE 
`sender_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'" OR
`receiver_name`="'.$_SESSION['username'].'"
ORDER BY `date_time` DESC';
$e='SELECT * from messages';
$r=mysqli_query($con,$q);


if($r){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($r)>0){
        $counter=0;
        $added_user=array();
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){
            $sender_name=$row['sender_name'];
            $receiver_name=$row['receiver_name'];
            $timestamp=$row['date_time'];
            if($_SESSION['username']==$sender_name){
                //add the receiver_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($receiver_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add receiver_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the receiver_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
                    <?php 
                    echo '<a href="?user='.$receiver_name.'">'.$receiver_name.'</a>';
                   $fetch_content=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while($row_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)){
                        $time=$row_fetch[5];
                        if($time<= time()){
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }else{
                            $status= "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                     echo $status;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as receiver_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$receiver_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }elseif($_SESSION['username']==$receiver_name){
                //add the sender_name but only once
                //so to do that check the user in array
                if(in_array($sender_name,$added_user)){
                    //dont add sender_name because
                    //he is already added
                }else{
                    //add the sender_name
                    ?>
                    <div class="grey-back">
                    <img src="images/s.jpg" class="image"/>
                    <?php echo '<a href="?user='.$sender_name.'">'.$sender_name.'</a>';
                      $fetch_content=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users JOIN status ON `users`.`id`=`status`.`user_id`");
                    while($row_fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($fetch_content)){
                        $time=$row_fetch[5];
                        if($time<= time()){
                            $status = "<img src='images/r.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }else{
                            $status= "<img src='images/a.png' height='10' width='10' style='float:right'>";
                        }
                    }
                     echo $status;
                    ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    //as sender_name added so
                    ///add it to the array as well
                    $added_user=array($counter=>$sender_name);
                    //increment the counter
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            }
        }
        else{
        //no message sent
        echo 'no user';
        }
    }else{
    //query problem
    echo $q;
}
if(isset($error)){
    print $error;

}

?>


<!-- end of left-col-container -->
</div>
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a way to detect when the user has closed the browser, see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20853978/2757519 . This should help steer you In the right direction