# How to log out user after closing browser ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I log in using `PasswordSignInAsync` function like

`var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Remember, shouldLockout: false);`

And field `model.Remember (isPersistent)` is false.

And in my Startup class, I have some code like

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });
```

What I would like to achieve is not only logging out the user after 30 minutes, but also after closing the browser.

Comment: You can't. there is no reliable way to detect a browser close.

Comment: Can you share your code that starts the logged in session? Is the Remember flag being passed to that correctly? if it is, the cookie should be non-persistent which means it'll be deleted when the browser is closed.

Comment: In debug mode I can clearly see that Remember flag is false. Maybe there is some trouble in my browser? I am using Chrome and have already tried uncheck options like `Continue where you left off` and `Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed`

Comment: try this - [detect browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event). in browser close event, you can logout.

Comment: May be dirty naive technique - What you can try is ask for a confirmation if user closes the browser. Get its event and on that event write an ajax method that calls Logout function of the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try clear cookie when `window.unload` from client side?
Maybe this resolve your problem.