# JavaScript: Detect only browser Close event instead of tab close and Refresh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I googled it before, but I could not find any solution about detecting **only window closing event** instead of tab closing and refresh events in JavaScript.

I used this code below which works for all cases: closing window, closing tab and also refresh page:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) { 
.. 
}
```

I could not find a solution to differentiate between the different cases, because my need is that I want only to detect window close not tab neither refresh.

Comment: I am not sure, but I assume that this is not possible. AFAIK a browser window is just a container for browser tabs. Closing a browser window will trigger closing all tabs but there is no message for this event.

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between a tab close and browser / window close actions.

Comment: but what about refresh action ? (thank you for your answers).

Comment: many discussions on this topic in stackoverflow. 
Some people have used workaround like below : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event/26275621#26275621

Comment: @pavanjoshi thank you but i saw these answers before but this did not help too, that's why i asked

Comment: ok @sohaieb,  i just meant that it is not possible directly to listen on it, so you need to find a workaround just suiting your use case.