# onbeforeunload confirmation before leaving the page not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to confirm before user leaves the page and I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080331/15573857) solution

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
</script>
```

but this only works when you interact with something on the page like maybe a clicking or typing, it doesn't work when you directly close the page

and I made a logging only popup page i.e. there is nothing on the page to interact with, so how do I still get it to confirm before leaving?

Comment: Probably `return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');`. Is simply returning a string supposed to show anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event

Comment: @C14L I tired adding `confirm()` it doesn't work

Comment: @HaukurHaf I tried the solution marked correct in the link you posed but that's not working either

Comment: @Jamiec could u elaborate on the link?

Comment: Have you tried clearing browser history

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran that shouldn't be a problem that directly effects the closing

Comment: @cakelover I believe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an event handler should call preventDefault() on the event.

So, you should at least do

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

---

However the docs also state

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

So you might be all out of luck with a completely empty page you have not interacted with.

Comment: shame to know there's no solution, I'll mark your answer correct

Comment: @cakelover Yup, Sad to find that, there is no solution :) I was giving my try also on my local, unless we interact with the page, No solution yet for tab close or browser close !!!