# browser closing event in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Before the browser is closed, I want to send data to the server that the user switches to the offline status.

After several days of studying the question, I have not found an answer.

How to track this event in vuejs/quasar framework?

Comment: You can use `beforeunload` event, which will trigger before the browser is closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to detect browser close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853142/trying-to-detect-browser-close-event)

Comment: Better if you provide some lines of code, and you can check this thread as well: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-detect-browser-tab-closing/114735

Comment: It's more about the `visibilityChange`. hence, you can achieve this by check for `visibilityState`. Here is the documentation link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Answer (score 4):

Getting idea from [the same question](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-detect-browser-tab-closing/114735) in Vue.js forum, here is a possible solution:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

const app = createApp({
  extends: App,  
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.leaving);
  },  
  methods: {
    leaving() {
      // Your code here
    },
  },
});

app.mount("#app");
```

You can play with [the complete example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-browser-f833g9) on CodeSandbox.

**Note:**

- Also tested with Firefox v99.0 and Chrome v101.0.4951.41 Desktop version.
- On Chrome, [the event won't be fired if the user did not interact with the page before closing](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss/c/VRzNnX0AJuo/m/PpSHPA_YAQAJ).
- `Window:beforeunload` event [may not be reliable on mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes).