# Calling a method on browser close

Tags: javascript

I want to call a server method on browser close, is their a way, I have tried

`window.onbeforeunload`

but this gets call even when I refresh the page, I want to call it only when browser is closed is their a work around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture browser close event in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622461/how-to-capture-browser-close-event-in-javascript)

Comment: @Elliot Frisco I don't think so, I have no way to differentiate the browser close and refresh event

Comment: It is exactly the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't differentiate between those events. Refreshing, loading another page or closing the browser is exactly the same (all the content is destroyed).